# Defining type class for a constrained type constructor

Tags: scala, types, scalaz, shapeless, type-constraints

I have this problem quite often, especially in places where shapeless is used, but can't find a reasonable solution. Being more specific, in my last case i wanted to define [scalaz Coyoneda](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.2.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Coyoneda.scala#L9) for [spray Directive](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-routing/src/main/scala/spray/routing/Directive.scala#L58), which is constrained by [shapeless HList](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/hlists.scala#L30). Attempt to do so gives a reasonable error:

```
Error:(6, 12) kinds of the type arguments (spray.routing.Directive,A,A) do not conform to the expected kinds of the type parameters (type F,type A,type B).
spray.routing.Directive's type parameters do not match type F's expected parameters:
type L's bounds <: shapeless.HList are stricter than type _'s declared bounds >: Nothing <: Any

  Coyoneda[Directive, A, A](dir)(identity)
           ^
```

Since the provided function (e.g `identity` in this case) knows about the constraint i guess that would be a valid definition. Is there anything that i'm missing from theoretical point and any way to define it?

Comment: What would you expect e.g. `map` to do on the resulting `Coyoneda[Directive, A]`?